# Multiline UIButton autosize per line

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nsattributedstring

I want to use the standard `UIButton` but the text I want to put on the `UIButton` has...

1. ... multiple lines (each line is different string) and ...
2. ... each line should have different font and size that  ...
3. ... automatically resizes font to fit the button width (not height to make it
   a bit easier)

[image]

So, even tough I would like to set the (preferred) font size for each line, I want the font-size to automatically size down so that **each separate line** fits nicely in the `UIButton` (=same behaviour as the `UILabel` AutoShrink / Minimum Font Scale).

*What I don't want:*

I do not want to start adding UILabels to the `UIButton` (as subview for example) or using IB put UILabels on a scene and just draw an UIButton around it (why: I want the standard `UIButton` highlighting behaviour)

*What I want:*

A clean solution using an attributed string, that given the width scales down the font (updates the attributed string I guess), line-by-line if required.

My idea, implement a function like this:

```
    func addToAttributedString(attString : NSMutableAttributedString, plainString : String, font : UIFont, preferredSize : CGFloat, maxWidth : CGFloat)
```

And then I could make the attributed string by calling this with text 1,2,3... and insert a newline (\n) between them.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you take UILabel instead of UIButton, you have "AutoShrink" option in xib to set "MinimumFontSize".

Answer (score 3):

`sizeToFit()` will help you to adjust height as the text.

```
    var str : NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Bla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla")
    str.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20), range: NSRange(location: 13,length: 3))
    button.setAttributedTitle(str, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
    button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    button.sizeToFit()
    button.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Working with your code too :

```
    var attrString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    addNewLineToAttributedString(attrString, plainString: "Big title", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), preferredSize: 50, maxWidth: 100)
    addNewLineToAttributedString(attrString, plainString: "Smaller text", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), preferredSize: 50, maxWidth: 100)
    addNewLineToAttributedString(attrString, plainString: "Smaller smaller text", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), preferredSize: 50, maxWidth: 100)
    addNewLineToAttributedString(attrString, plainString: "Smaller Smaller Smaller text", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), preferredSize: 50, maxWidth: 100)
    addNewLineToAttributedString(attrString, plainString: "Smaller Smaller Smaller text", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), preferredSize: 50, maxWidth: 100)
    addNewLineToAttributedString(attrString, plainString: "Big title", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), preferredSize: 50, maxWidth: 100)
    addNewLineToAttributedString(attrString, plainString: "Big title", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), preferredSize: 50, maxWidth: 100)
    addNewLineToAttributedString(attrString, plainString: "Smaller Smaller Smaller text", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), preferredSize: 50, maxWidth: 100)
    addNewLineToAttributedString(attrString, plainString: "Smaller Smaller Smaller text", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), preferredSize: 50, maxWidth: 100)
    addNewLineToAttributedString(attrString, plainString: "Smaller Smaller Smaller text", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), preferredSize: 50, maxWidth: 100)
    addNewLineToAttributedString(attrString, plainString: "Smaller Smaller Smaller text", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), preferredSize: 50, maxWidth: 100)
    button.setAttributedTitle(attrString, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
    button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    button.sizeToFit()
    button.layoutIfNeeded()
```

[image]

Comment: tried this but it didn't provide the required results. Note that the 4 strings separated by \n also have different font (underline, bold) and different preferred size

Comment: Yes of course its working with my code because addNewLineToAttributedString adjusts the size of the string for the width!

Comment: @HixField without your code also it worked. as I have added before.

Comment: @HixField anyways leave it, If you got the output. Thanks

Comment: thanks for trying, check out my revised answer below, now using extension and overloading operators (much cleaner code).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using Storyboard it self. Just perform this steps

1: Change Button Type from **System** to **Custome** .

[image]

2: Change Button Title From **plain** to **attributed**.

3: Enter the text in textArea and  press **Alt + Enter** when u need a newLine. see image it will break my text into 3 line .

[image]

4: Now set line break mode to **Character Wrap**.

[image]

**NOTE:** If you don't see the text in different line in storyboard change the text align from **Align natural  to Align left**. set as select portion in image

[image]

5: Now select individual line and set font. U can also change the textColor.

[image]

6: Repeat **Step5** for each line.

here is my simulator output:

[image]

Comment: +1 for ALT - ENTER to start new line! However, sorry for not specifying this in the org question, but the text is set programmatically. I figured out a solution see my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution (have a look at my blog http://www.hixfield.net/blog/2015/06/multiline-uibutton-with-each-line-resized-to-fit-width/ for more info)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //the button that we are formatting
    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!

    //setup our button in the will appear function
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        setupBtn()
    }

    //function that does the magic
    func setupBtn() {
        btn.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        var attrString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        var attr = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)]
        attrString += (NSMutableAttributedString(string : "Big title", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(50), maxWidth: 100)! + "\n" )
        attrString += (NSMutableAttributedString(string : "Smaller text", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(50), maxWidth: 100)!  + "\n" )
        attrString += (NSMutableAttributedString(string : "Smaller smaller text", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(80), maxWidth: 100)! + "\n" )
        btn.setAttributedTitle(attrString, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}

//************************

extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    /**Makes an attributes string with the specified (plain) string and font but resizes the font smaller
    to fit the width if required. Can return nil, if there is no way to make it fit*/
    convenience init?(string : String, font : UIFont, maxWidth : CGFloat){
        self.init()
        for var size = font.pointSize ; size>1 ; size-- {
            let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : font.fontWithSize(size)]
            let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attrs)
            if attrString.size().width <= maxWidth {
                self.setAttributedString(attrString)
                return
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

//************************

public func += (inout left: NSMutableAttributedString, right: NSAttributedString) {
    left.appendAttributedString(right)
}

public func + (left: NSAttributedString, right: NSAttributedString) -> NSAttributedString {
    var result  = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: right)
    result.appendAttributedString(right)
    return result
}

public func + (left: NSAttributedString, right: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    var result  = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: left)
    result.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: right))
    return result
}
```

[image]